# porque no tengo la caracterisitica windows hypervision plataform

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Quiero corrrer una aplicacion xamaryn. Me "Andorid_accelerated_x86_Oreo en HyPper-v, es necesario haber instalado y habilitado window hipervisor platform". Tengo window 10 pro. Es necesario el enterprise?. Lei que con el PRO es suficiente. La caracteristica windows hipervisor plataform no lo tengo en la lista de caracteristicas para poder activarlo, en cambio el hiper v si y ya lo active. Tengo la ultima version 1803, actualizad en junio de este año. Graciass.

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien le ayuda. Mi error fue: No haber leido todas las características de window para activar o desactivar. Visual studio me informaba que debia activar window hypervision platform. Como tengo window 10 en español la opcion es "plataforma de hipervisor para window". Error muy basico. Saludos.